# What is this Ribbon Cable Connector called?

Tags: connector, identification, ribbon-cable

Even after extensive scrolling through Google Image Search, I could not find this connector or one similar to it: [image: four images of a white connector attached to a 6-pin(?) ribbon cable]

I am especially interested in finding the mating connector.

Comment: Good pictures. If you ask for connector types next time, include at least the pitch and if possible some dimensions. This simplifies search greatly!

Comment: Good advice! Will do next time! :)

Comment: That's ribbon cable, not what's typically called FFC

Comment: @ScottSeidman You can always edit the question :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like Micromodul Series 30 from [Lumberg](http://www.lumberg.com/en/products/sortiment/more-pcb-systems).

[image]
[image]